# New Raspberry Pi 4 boots to black screen

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I'm pretty new to the Raspberry Pi world and I just bought my first one (4 model B 8GB). I downloaded the raspberry pi OS full (23-BIT) and used the Raspberry Pi Imager to put on my Samsung 64GB Sd card. When I put the SD Card back in my Raspberry Pi and plug the power cable as well as the HDMI one, I get a black screen on my monitor.
I have no idea what I did wrong, can you please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the boot sector of the SD card that is normally accessible from Windows, I edited the file config.txt and I uncommented the line :

hdmi_force_hotplug=1